# remove element by value in list Python fastest

Tags: python, list, performance, optimization

what is the fastest way to remove an element from a list by its value?

I believe `list.remove("element_to_be_removed")` is the naive way. How can we optimize it?

Comment: The way to optimize it is to not use a list — use a set, dict, or something else that allows you to do O(1) lookups and removals.

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do it to any significant degree. By the nature of lists identifying the element in the list is O(n) and you really aren't going to get around that.

Comment: can I convert my list into a set first & them perform remove from that set to make the removal faster? P.s. I know my list will/ should only have unique entries so converting to set won't be an issue. @Samwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding an element in a list by value is O(n), as is removing it once you have found it.  There is no way to reduce this; it's inherent in how lists are built.

Finding and/or removing an element in a set is O(1).

Converting a list into a set is O(n).  If you have a list and you need to remove one item, converting it to a set and then removing one item doesn't get you to O(1), because the set conversion itself is an O(n) operation.  You're better off using `list.remove()`.

If you have a list of unique items, and you anticipate needing to remove many items from it in an unordered way (say, you're going to eventually remove each item one by one), you can change that from an O(n^2) operation to an O(n) operation by converting the entire list into a set (once, in O(n)) and then removing the elements one by one after that (in O(1) per item, hence O(n) overall).

The ideal solution (if possible) is to anticipate the ways in which you'll need to use this collection of items and make it a set *from the beginning* if the functionality of a set is a better fit for what you're doing.

Comment: Also using a list comprehension we can remove an element in O(n).

Comment: Not exactly -- you can use a list comprehension to build a new list that excludes the element you want to remove.  Mutating the existing list to match the new list is another step (but it's also O(n) so it doesn't change the overall big-O time).

Answer (score 0):

A list is unordered, so finding an element by its value *must* be done by exhaustive search (best case O(1), worst O(n)).

Deletion also takes O(n) operations, but more precisely, it takes the number of shifts equal to the number of elements that follow the deleted one. (Plus occasional halving when the list shrinks a lot). So we have worst case O(n), best O(1), symmetrically with the search.

So if you perform the search for the key backward, the best case of removal is O(1) instead of O(n), though on average this makes absolutely no difference.

Last hint: if you have some reason to believe that the removals occur more often on a side than on the other, you'd better organize your list so that this side comes to the right (store backward if needed) and perform backward searches.